# Activating taskbar icon in C#

Tags: c#, c++, winforms

I have in following code in C++ side of my application for activating taskbar icon. I've used [ITaskbarList shell interface](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb774652%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

```
    DECLARE_INTERFACE_(ITaskbarList,IUnknown)
    {
    STDMETHOD(QueryInterface)(THIS_ REFIID riid,LPVOID* ppvObj) PURE;
    STDMETHOD_(ULONG,AddRef)(THIS) PURE;
    STDMETHOD_(ULONG,Release)(THIS) PURE;
    STDMETHOD(ActiveTab)(HWND) PURE;
    STDMETHOD(AddTab)(HWND) PURE;
    STDMETHOD(DeleteTab)(HWND) PURE;
    STDMETHOD(HrInit)(HWND) PURE;
    };
```

//

```
  ITaskbarList *p_taskbar = NULL; 
  CoCreateInstance(CLSID_TaskbarList, 0, 
    CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER, IID_ITaskbarList, (void**)&p_taskbar);

  p_taskbar->ActivateTab(hwnd);
```

I there is something similar in c#? (So I can call this activation there) Is it possible to get object with ITaskbarList interface in c#?

Mainform of my application is `System.Windows.Forms.Form`. I want to activate it's icon on taskbar.

Comment: Where's the `ITaskbarList` from? Couldn't you search and find **which assembly** and **namespace** it's located in? I've not searched yet, but the common thing between C# and C++ is **.NET framework** and other libraries. They can use the same libraries, they can access to the underlying `Win32` stuff. that's all.

Comment: Sure you can do exactly the same from C#. Declare the interface. Create it with `CoCreateInstance`. And off you go. You'll surely find what you need here: http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/WindowsAPICodePack

Comment: @KingKing The C++ code here is native rather than managed. It's not in a .net assembly. So this needs interop. Not difficult as it happens.